# How to make control on Foreach loop while executing it with Selenium driver?

Tags: java, selenium, foreach

I try to retrieve text via foreach loop,as according to page wise. Flow is : It prints text of single row and as soon as it completes, it goes to second page and start again to retrieve text. Problem is, it retrieves data of first page multiple times like sometimes 2 or 3 or 4 times, How to control it for single time execution ?

```
    if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='currentPage=currentPage+1']")).isEnabled()) {

        int ilength = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@ng-attr-id='{{item.attr}}']")).size();

        Outer: for (int i1 = ilength; i1 > 0;) {
            List<WebElement> findData = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@ng-attr-id='{{item.attr}}']"));
            for (WebElement webElement : findData) {
                String printGroupName = webElement.getAttribute("value").toString();
                System.out.println(printGroupName);
                ilength--;
            }

            if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='currentPage=currentPage+1']")).isEnabled()) {
                action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='currentPage=currentPage+1']"))).click().perform();
                page.pagecallingUtility();
                ilength = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@ng-attr-id='{{item.attr}}']")).size();
            } else {
                break Outer;
            }
        }

    } else {
        List<WebElement> findAllGroupName = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@ng-attr-id='{{item.attr}}']"));

        for (WebElement webElement : findAllGroupName) {
            String printGroupName = webElement.getAttribute("value").toString();
            System.out.println(printGroupName);
        }
    }
```

[image: HTML Page]

Console Data, on which it retrieve information [image: Console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop can be simplified as below.

```
boolean newPageOpened = true;
while (newPageOpened) {
    List<WebElement> findData = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@ng-attr-id='{{item.attr}}']"));
    for (WebElement webElement : findData) {
        if (webElement.isDisplayed()) {
            String printGroupName = webElement.getAttribute("value").toString();
            System.out.println(printGroupName);
        }
    }

    WebElement nextButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='currentPage=currentPage+1']"));
    if (nextButton.isEnabled()) {
        action.moveToElement(nextButton).click().perform();
        page.pagecallingUtility();
    } else {
        newPageOpened = false;
    }
}
```

As for the contents of the fist page printing again and again, I suspect when you open the second page the contents of the first page are simply hidden in the  page. So when you use `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@ng-attr-id='{{item.attr}}']"))` the hidden first page elements are also found. The simple solution is to check if the element is displayed before printing it.